# Pythonic ways to re-group / pivot database output

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a situation I often find myself in with Python and I'm sure my solution could be a little more elegant. The simplest analogy I can make is a table of comments in a photo app; every comment links to a specific album and a specific photo. Picture something like this:

```
|------------|----------|----------|---------------|
| comment_id | album_id | photo_id | comment       |
|------------|----------|----------|---------------|
|     1      |     1    |     1    | Wheres this?  |
|     2      |     1    |     1    | Yosemite, CA  |
|     3      |     1    |     2    | Nice photo!   |
|------------|----------|----------|---------------|
```

When we go to render an album, getting the data out is easy enough:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT comment_id, photo_id, comment FROM db.comments WHERE album_id= 1')
comments_atomic = cursor.fetchall()
```

At this point, comments_atomic will look like this:

```
({'comment_id': 1, 
  'photo_id': 1, 
  'comment': 'Wheres this?'},
 {'comment_id': 2, 
  'photo_id': 1, 
  'comment': 'Yosemite, CA'},
 {'comment_id': 3, 
  'photo_id': 2, 
  'comment': 'Nice photo!'})
```

I *could* render my comments by pausing once at each photo, iterating through the complete array and printing only the comments with a matching photo_id. But that would be horrible. So I do this:

```
comments = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for val in comments_atomic:
    comments[val['photo_id']][val['comment_id']] = {'comment': val['comment']}
```

This gives me this nice nested dictionary keyed on photo_id:

```
({1: {1: {comment: 'Wheres this?'},
      2: {comment: 'Yosemite, CA' }}
 {2: {3: {comment: 'Nice photo!'  }})
```

Checking if there are comments for any photo is as easy as checking photo_id exists as a key in the comments dictionary. You can then iterate over comments[n] to render everything, and you're not needlessly iterating over comments that belong to other photos.

So my question is:

1. Is there a more efficient way to reshape my data structure?
2. Is there another approach that would negate the need to reshape the data at all?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your sample data, the last comment in `comments_atomic` should be under photo_id 2 right?

Comment: Also a syntax error with the single-quote in the string "Where's this?"

Comment: Great catch - thank you! Fixed both. Sorry, I wrote this freehand instead of doing it in Python because... I really  don't have a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` if you want to get a little tricky and flex your pythonista skills:

```
from itertools import groupby
temp = {k:list(g) for k,g in groupby(ca, lambda x: x['photo_id'])}
# I shortened the name comments_atomic to ca here
```

This will give you the intermediate result of:

```
{1: [{'comment': "Where's this?", 'comment_id': 1, 'photo_id': 1},
     {'comment': 'Yosemite, CA', 'comment_id': 2, 'photo_id': 1}],
 2: [{'comment': 'Nice photo!', 'comment_id': 3, 'photo_id': 2}]}
```

Now flatten the whole thing with a nested `dict` comprehension:

```
{pnum:{c['comment_id']:c['comment'] for c in cs} for pnum,cs in temp.items()}
```

Resulting in:

```
{1: {1: "Where's this?", 2: 'Yosemite, CA'}, 2: {3: 'Nice photo!'}}
```

Which I believe is somewhat like your intended output!

**Edit:** I realize it's not exactly your intended output but I think I've given you some new pythonic tools with `groupby` and `dict` comprehensions. Fixing the mismatch is left as an exercise to the reader. >:)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! The output doesn't need to be identical - the grouping around album is the spirit of the question, and I think this ticks that box.

I've already got one more answer than I expected but I'd like to leave this for a few more hours just in case anybody can think of (yet another) way to tackle this.Thanks - you're a shoe in for yet another answer ;)

Comment: Cool, it was a fun morning puzzle for me so I got what I needed out of it. I'd also like to see some other approaches if others have ideas, so no pressure to accept:)

Comment: You're a winner! Thanks again. Wish everyone I work with was this helpful. Leave Hawaii and join us ;)